# Cisco ASA 5505 and slow download speeds for Apple devices

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa, apple, network-speed

For traffic routing through my ASA 5505, downloads for all Apple devices, including

- AppleTV
- iPad gen 1
- IMac
- MacBook Pro

are very slow.  speedof.me show less than 1 Mbps download (where I should have 20 Mbps +), yet for any Windows-based device, the download speeds are in excess of 20 Mbps.  The Windows device, including the iMac and MacBook Pro machines, are connected via ethernet cable.

Why are Apple devices experiencing such pain?  Is it an ASA setting, or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you plug the Macs upstream of the ASA (directly to your ISP's router/modem) and see if you get the same behavior? That'll narrow it down to an ASA or Mac issue.

Comment: Yeah, I did exactly that, and the download speeds were screaming fast.  All signs point to the ASA.  What I don't understand, though, is why only Apple products?

Answer (score 2):

This *could* be an MTU issue... I'm assuming you have an intermediate device between the ASA firewall and your Apple *wireless* devices. Your Cisco ASA is not a wireless access point. Please check that intermediate device and provide more information about it...

There's nothing inherent to the use of a Cisco ASA 5505 that would impact or prevent good throughput to Apple equipment.

Comment: You are correct.  There is a D-Link 665 gigabit router which provides the 192.168.x.x home network.  I've also tried replacing this with an Apple router (last night, in fact), taking default settings, and the behaviour was the same, leading me to think that the problem lay in the ASA.  Could you please elaborate on the MTU angle?  On the ASA, values are set at the default 1500.

Comment: Could you test with the AP in bridge mode rather than the routed mode?